# Can't connect to Postgres through psql in Windows10

Tags: postgresql, connectivity

I am running `psql` from Windows command prompt but it is showing error.

I have to change listen address but I don't where it is? Where to find listen addresses in PostgreSQL settings?.

```
    C:\Users\KUMAR>psql -U postgres psql 
    could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) 
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

When I try to connect, it declines. After going to `psql` page they are telling to change listen address. The Windows service is running. I configured the default port 5432 during installation.

Comment: Check [`listen_address`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS) in your [`postgresql.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html) maybe it's only listening on IPv4 but psql tries to use IPv6

Comment: where I will find postgresql.conf?

Comment: As [stated in the manual I linked to](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-CONFIGURATION-FILE) "*which is normally kept in the data directory*" - you specified the data directory during installation